# Model.updateOne() is executed before Document.save() - mongoose.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am trying to learn using MongoDB with mongoose.js.
I want to insert a document and update it. When I run app.js it logs "Successfully updated" but there is no modification when I preview it in mongo shell i.e. review: "Pretty Red." remains unchanged.

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB'; //creates fruitsDB

// Connect to database server
mongoose.connect(url, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

// Define a schema/table structure
const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "No name specified. Try Again!"] //validation with error message
  },
  rating: {
    type: Number,
    min: 1, //validation
    max: 10 //validation
  },
  review: String
});

// Create a model from the structure
const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

// Create a document that follows a model
const fruit = new Fruit({
  name: "Apple",
  rating: 6,
  review: "Pretty Red."
});

// Save the new document/entry
fruit.save();

// Update single document
Fruit.updateOne({name: "Apple"}, {review: "Review Changed!"}, function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Successfully updated.");
  }
});
```

Comment: Try `await fruit.save()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the .save() return a promise, await it will do.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use $set like this:

```
// Mongoose sends a `updateOne({ _id: doc._id }, { $set: { name: 'foo' } })`
```

Doc: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating

For your case:

```
Fruit.updateOne({name: "Apple"}, { $set : {review: "Review Changed!"}}, function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Successfully updated.");
  }
});
```

Comment: didn't make a difference. update function runs before save.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its the problem with awaiting the returned promise from document.save();
in mongoDB each time you deal with DB, like create, findOne, updateOne, delete etc., these all return promises and you will have to await them.